# Fullcalendar - is it possible to have various background colors?

Tags: fullcalendar

Currently, we have a setup where Saturday and Sunday are marked grey all the way down (vertically), symbolizing that the days are off. However, we would like to mark individual days off as well via the grey marking, e.g. one only working Monday - Thursday, then on that person Friday - Sunday needs to be marked grey.

Is that possible - and how?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the businessHours setting, and/or Background Events - both are described in the documentation

Comment: I forgot to mention we use timeline view, so no hours, only days. 

Is it possible to mark the background on different days for different people, so only the squares marked. 

My developers have gone through the documentation

Comment: Yes, businessHours can still do that - you can specify date ranges, it doesn't have to include hours. Don't be fooled by the name, the documentation makes clear the hours are not mandatory. businessHours only works if the pattern is fixed every week though. If the pattern can vary, then use a feed of Background Events instead.

Comment: If your developers went through the documentation, then they should already know what to do. If they still don't, or they encountered a problem when trying to implement the requirement, they should ask a specific question on here directly concerning their exact issue, and show any relevant code which is giving them trouble. If you yourself are not a developer, or at least aren't writing the code for this calendar feature in your app, then a discussion on a programming website about programming problems is unlikely to be a very productive one for you.

Comment: Thank you. I have forwarded your response to my developers and told them to add specific issues here. Thank you !

Comment: No problem. I suggest deleting this vague question, and getting the developers to post new, more specific questions with the fullCalendar tag, I and others look at that tag's question feed pretty often. That way if they wrote their own question, they can edit it properly and so on, unless you give them access to your SO account to edit this one. Make sure they read [ask] and how to create a [mre] of their issue, before posting anything.